# Problem interacting with Shadow Dom with Selenium in Node.js

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I have a website ingbusiness.pl/gib/login, I need to basically log in (send keys, and then click the orange button). When I try to execute such function:

```
 async function getExtShadowRoot() { 
let shadowHost;
shadowHost = await driver.findElement(By.css("ing-app-gib-main")); 
return await shadowHost.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot")} }
```

I get error TypeError: shadowHost.executeScript is not a function

How to access the shadowRoot?

Answer (score 0):

use driver instead of shadowHost to executeScript.

return await drive.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",shadowHost );